# Align scatter plot to right side in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

See the demo link  here[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/p2MF6/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        <some codes>
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        },{
            name: 'indicator',
            data: [5],
            type: 'scatter',
            marker:{
                //here you can have your url
                symbol: 'circle',
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

I am trying to align the scatter plots which currently center aligned respective to the column chart. I want those to be right aligned respective to the column chart

Comment: On the right side of the column, or in between the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement) parameter with number value.

Answer (score 1):

For a category chart you can still specify an x-value in your data series.  An x-value of N.25, is the right edge of the column, 0.25, 1.25, 2.25, etc...

```
       {
            name: 'indicator',
            data: [[0.25,5]],
            type: 'scatter',
            marker:{
                //here you can have your url
                symbol: 'circle',
            }
        }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2MF6/7/).